# PHP: RSS parsing

Tags: php, parsing, rss

I want to parse a websites news section. It has a RSS subscribe button but the outlook looks odd and I'm not sure how to parse it.

http://www.networkroi.co.uk/DesktopModules/ArticleManager/ArticleRss.aspx?id=324&pid=0

It's not in XML which would have been a lot easier.

Here is the news page with that link on it - http://www.networkroi.co.uk/News/tabid/99/Default.aspx

I would like to parse it with PHP if possible, though I really just want to dislay the info as it looks there..

Any help most appreciated

Jonesy

Comment: This feed does not validate. http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.networkroi.co.uk%2FDesktopModules%2FArticleManager%2FArticleRss.aspx%3Fid%3D324%26pid%3D0 - But it is XML nevertheless

Comment: possible duplicate of [What RSS parser should I use in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656767/what-rss-parser-should-i-use-in-php) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464543/rss-feeds-in-php and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250679/best-way-to-parse-rss-atom-feeds-with-php and more general http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rss+parser+php

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at excellent [SimplePie](http://simplepie.org/) class for parsing rss feeds with PHP.

> SimplePie is a very fast and
>   easy-to-use class, written in PHP,
>   that puts the 'simple' back into
>   'really simple syndication'. Flexible
>   enough to suit beginners and veterans
>   alike, SimplePie is focused on speed,
>   ease of use, compatibility and
>   standards compliance.