# Target RSS value in PHP

Tags: php, rss

I'm making RSS feed reader with PHP and i get all feed content, but i can't figure out hot to target RSS values so i can echo them, style them, etc!

[this is the feed](http://www.riga.lv/rss/lv/PressRelease/)

my script so far:

```
foreach($feed_list as $from => $feeds) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($feeds);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($xml);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

[I get this out after code executes](http://pastebin.com/N4EJECp2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for trouble, but i found out how

```
<?php
$rss = simplexml_load_file('http://www.riga.lv/rss/lv/PressRelease/');
?>
<h1><?php echo $rss->channel->title; ?></h1>
<ul>
<?php
foreach($rss->channel->item as $e) {
    echo "<li><a href=\"".$e->link['href']."\">";
    echo $e->title;     
    echo "</a></li>\n";
}    
?>
```

[Thanks to this :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464543/rss-feeds-in-php) - Thanks Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to traverse the `$xml` object returned and get the values for each single node... check http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php for more info.