# How to get started using a web service from another domain?

Tags: php, web-services, web

PHP beginner here. Apologies if this has been posted in another form - I've looked but since I'm unsure specifically what I'm looking for I'm also unsure specifically what to search for.

Essentially - My town has a number of web services posted at http://data.brisbane.qld.gov.au/index.php/datasets/page/2/ - A number of these are web services. What should I research in order to learn how to query and the display results from these web services on my own domain?

Comment: do they offer an API to their service?

Comment: @GeoPhoenix I'm unsure - how can I check this? Beginner, beginner - have only consumed SharePoint web services previously and looking for some direction to begin

Comment: it looks that you can only Fetch (RSS,CSV) and not submit queries directly to the database, you can manipulate the data you receive from rss,csv ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that most web services on this site are RSS feeds, so you can grab these data and parse them. Reading RSS via PHP is well explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464543/rss-feeds-in-php).